# Bootstrap datepicker converted to java util date

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker. I am getting date from the date input box and storing in database using Java code.

If the date in bootstrap date picker MM/dd/yyyy (10/1/2014) then when persisting in database its storing as a different date with one year difference or one month difference like that. I cant predict the change.

I am getting the date from the datepicker and storing it as java.util.Date object.

example:

11/01/2014

Fri Jan 10 18:00:00 CST 2014

I dont know whether in date conversion I am doing problem or its problem with bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [SimpleDateFormater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(sdate);
```